# Integrating a function without u-substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to figure out how to Integrate a function like that without the use of $u-$substitution. Would really appreciate some help here!

$$\int\ln^2 x\,dx$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate by parts:
$$\int \ln^2 x\,dx = x\ln^2 x-\int 2\ln x\,dx = x\ln^2 x-2\left(x\ln x-x+C\right), C \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Gibbs, how would you go on about solving it with $u$-substitution?

Comment: I do not know. Even if I try a substitution I end up using integration by parts.